# What are the scenes in action movies where two cars try to ram each other head-on called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, cinema

You know, like when one guy in one car "takes" on the other guy in another car "athwart" the alleyway in a deadly chicken-play and whoever "flinches" first is the "loser/pussy". Such scenes are present in *Last Action Hero, Sense8* and a lot of other 80s and 90s action movies. I know there's a "proper" name for such scenes I just can't seem, for the love of me, to remember it.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: This may be better suited for Movies&TV SE.

Comment: I did a thorough google search. Nothing useful came up.

Comment: It's been known to teenagers for decades as "a game of chicken".

Comment: Yes, but it's been known to the insiders/filmmakers under an entirely different name (at least in northern England)... which I can't seem to recall now.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will try some movie-nut sites if nothing shakes loose here.

Comment: @user74809, SHOWDOWN certainly makes sense. Why not make it an answer  (for the benifit of other users).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game is called **chicken.**

*The name "chicken" has its origins in a game in which two drivers drive towards each other on a collision course: one must swerve, or both may die in the crash, but if one driver swerves and the other does not, the one who swerved will be called a "chicken," meaning a coward*
**Wikipedia**

*Adjective sense of "cowardly" is at least as old as 14c. (compare hen-herte "a chicken-hearted person," mid-15c.). As the name of a game of danger to test courage, it is first recorded 1953.* **Etymology Online**

Comment: Ah, I just remembered it. Such scenes are called SHOWDOWN scenes in filmmaker's parlance! But thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

**just remembered!**!

It's called SHOWDOWN sequence(scene). After an action sequence/scene (a chase) comes a showdown sequence (a sequence, for example, where two brinkmen put on a chicken play(as it is known in film jargon) or in other words where two guys play "chicken" with each others to see who pussies out.

Comment: "Showdown" covers a broader range of confrontations, not necessarily involving "playing chicken".  It could be a fist fight, eg.  And the classical "showdown" is the gunfight where it's not a matter of not "flinching" first, but rather being a quicker draw and better aim than the other guy.